# Jenkins build runs script that exit 1 but it doesn't mark the build as a failure

Tags: jenkins

In Jenkins configuration, I have the following code:

```
sh example.sh test
```

example.sh has the following code:

```
aws s3 cp ./Bucket $S3BUCKET --recursive --content-type "video/mp4" --cache-control "max-age=$MAXAGE" --exclude "*" --include "*.mp4" --profile $PROFILE

if [ "$?" -ne 0 ]; then
    exit 1
fi
```

When I look at the console output, there is an error running the command above, but it doesn't exit 1 and mark the build as a failure. I see the error text "Could not deploy files to S3 bucket" but the build isn't marked as a failure. So exit 1 doesn't run.

Why is that happenning?

Comment: Have you tried running `aws s3 cp...` command manually to see if it correctly sets $? on error? Also in the jenkins script '-e' flag might be unset somewhere before with the command `set +e`.

Comment: what do you mean by Also in the jenkins script '-e' flag might be unset somewhere before with the command set +e

Comment: I meant that by default Jenkins shell script calls shell with flags `-xe`. -x is for extensive logging and `-e` is for aborting the script execution as soon as any command returns non-zero exit code.

Comment: what do I do to make sure jenkins aborts with a failure if any command returns a non-zero exit code?

Comment: should I be doing sh -xe example.sh test

Comment: Please do some experiments and ensure your script returns proper exit codes.

Comment: I did that. it returns exit 1, but jenkins doesn't recognize the exit 1

Comment: Do you use a regular Shell Build Step?

Comment: Could you pass extra logging flags to your script? Like this: `sh -vx example.sh test`. Also: have your tried to enforce Jenkins to fail the build? just call `exit 1` in the shell build step - does it fail the build?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Log Parser Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Log+Parser+Plugin) to check if the **Could not deploy files to S3 bucket** text is in the output and fail the build if so

Comment: This might be a valid fix but that does not answer the question.

Comment: aws command as-is return with exit code 0 in any case so you can't rely on its exit code. Instead you can check the output for the error text

Comment: No aws command actually returns non-zero when there is an error. The problem is when I call exit 1 - jenkins doesn't fail the build.

Comment: So it may be the wrapping Jenkins step issue or an issue with your if statement. Why do you use brackets to wrap the $? value?
Try to change it to:
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    exit 1
fi